# Why am i getting this error when i compile my code in devc++?

Tags: c++

I want to pass address of object `e` but I am getting this error:

```
D:\Timecal1\timecal.cpp In function 'int main()':
101 9   D:\Timecal1\timecal.cpp [Error] invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'entry&' from an rvalue of type 'entry*'
97  7   D:\Timecal1\timecal.cpp [Note] in passing argument 1 of 'void menu(entry&)
```

What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>

//definitions
#define s ' '

using namespace std;

class date{
    private :
        int day;
        string month;
        int year;

        public:
            date()
            {
                day=0;
                month="NULL";
                year=0;
            }

            void vwrite(ostream &o)
            {
                o<<day<<'/'<<month<<'/'<<year;
            }
};

// overloading << operator for class date
ostream& operator<<(ostream &o,date &d)
{
    d.vwrite(o);
    return o;
}

class time{
    private:
        int hours;
        int mins;

    public:
        time()
        {
            hours=0;
            mins=0;
        }

        void vwrite(ostream &o)
        {
            o<<hours<<':'<<mins;
        }
};

// overloading operator << for time
ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, time &t)
{
    t.vwrite(o);
    return o;
}

class entry
{
    private:
        int sno;
        date d;
        time t;
        int mowd;

    public:
        entry() //constructor
        {
            sno=0;      
            mowd=0;
        }


        void vwrite(ostream &o)
        {
            o<<sno<<". "<<d<<s<<t<<s<<mowd;
        }
};


// overloading operator << for entry
ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, entry &e)
{
    e.vwrite(o);
    return o;
}



int main()
{
    void menu(entry&);
    entry e;
    cout<<sizeof(entry)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(e)<<endl;
    menu(&e);
    return 0;
}


void menu(entry &e)
{
    cout<<"\nWhat would you like to do? : ";
    cout<<"\n1. Read entries\n";
    cout<<"\n2. Enter time entries\n";
    cout<<"\n3. Modify a time sheet\n";
    cout<<"\n4. Calculate total\n";
    cout<<"\n5. Delete a time sheet\n";
    cout<<"\n6. Exit\n";
    cout<<endl;
    int x=0;
    cin>>x;
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1 :
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\nRead entries\n";
            cout<<e;
            break;

        case 2 :
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\nEnter time entries\n";
            break;

        case 3 :
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\nModify a time sheet\n";
            break;

        case 4 :
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\nCalculate total\n";
            break;

        case 5 :
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\nDelete a time sheet\n";
            break;

        case 6 :
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\nExiting\n";
            break;

        default :
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\nInvalid input\n";
            break;      
    }
}
```

Comment: @cigien please explain "menu(&e); --> menu(e);"

Comment: it works fine if i pass e as an object but not as a reference. why?

Comment: `#define s ' '` is dangerous. It will replace any `s` tokens in your code silently and without thinking about whether it's a good idea or not. The resulting compiler errors can be utterly bizarre. Prefer `constexpr char <descriptive name here> = ' ';` or just use `' '`.

Comment: i see. im not familiar with constexpr char <descriptive name here> = ' '; i will have to check. thanks!

Comment: [Documentation for `constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** - The prototype declaration

```
void menu(entry&);
```

must be outside the `main` function.

**2** - `menu` has a reference parameter, it means that whatever variable you pass it, it will take a reference to the variable, not a copy of it like normally, so you just have to pass the variable. If you pass the variable with the address-of operator `&` it's as if you are passing a reference to the reference of the variable, so you must use the variable itself:

```
menu(e);
```

`menu(&e)` would be used if your parameter was a pointer, like

```
void menu(entry*);
```

meaning you would have to pass the address of your variable.

Answer (score 2):

When you make a call like this:

```
menu(&e);
```

you are passing the *address* of `e` to `menu`. It seems you think this call is passing a *reference*, but it's not.

But `menu` expects an `entry&`, so you need to call it like this:

```
menu(e);
```

Comment: oh i see. but if we declare the prototype to take the address, shouldn't we pass an address as menu(&e) instead of menu(e)?

Comment: You did not declare the prototype to take an address. You declared it to take a reference. Different things with unfortunately similar terminology. Passing an object via a pointer ( `entry*`) is a type of pass by reference, but in c++ `entry&` literally means pass a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem of your code is that you have:

```
using namespace std;
```

But the name of one of your classes is `time`, that can have a conflict with `std::time`.